# Which library to refer for Iptc4xmpExt in python?

Tags: xmp, iptc, pyexiv2

I am currently using iptcExt from pyexiv2 Module but my main requirement is use Iptc4xmpExt and that is not available in pyexiv2, so which library or module I need to import in python to create Iptc4xmpExt meta information?

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/python-xmp-toolkit/python-xmp-toolkit to directly manipulate the xmp data.